# How to loop through an array of addresses and send ether

Tags: solidity, ether

I am trying to figure out how, after adding addresses to the `addressArray` Array via the `addAddressandShareAmount` function, can I loop through each address and send each address 1 ether
via the `payShareHolders` function? Thanks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract MyWallet {
    
    address[] addressArray;
    uint[] shareAmountArray;
    
    function receive() external payable{
    }
    
    function addAddressandShareAmount(address payable adrs, uint numberOfShares) public {
        require(msg.sender == 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
        addressArray.push(adrs);
        shareAmountArray.push(numberOfShares);
    }
    
    function getPosition(uint index) public view returns (address) {
        return addressArray[index];
    }
    
    function payShareHolders(address payable address1, uint256 amount1) public {
        require(msg.sender == 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);
        for(addressArray[0]; addressArray[addressArray.length]){
            address.transfer(1 ether);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question right, you might want to check the method for writing for-loops in Solidity. The Solidity docs have a great section called [Solidity By Example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html) which can be a great reference for how to use things.

Also, there are a few different ways to send ether using Solidity. You use `transfer` in your code, so we'll give an example for that, but for anyone reading this: you may want to look into the differences between `transfer`, `send`, and `call`. ([Here](https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/)'s one potential resource from searching "solidity send ether".)

You also might want to research the `payable` keyword. ([This](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#address) might be a good place to start.) In short, you need to kind of whitelist what can receive ether in your code in Solidity.

In general, the syntax is something like:

```
for(uint256 i=0; i < array.length; i++){
  // put your logic here
}
```

In your case, this would mean something like:

```
for(uint256 i=0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
    address payable addr = addressArray[i];
    addr.transfer(1 ether);
}
```

or the same thing using `call`:

```
for(uint256 i=0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
    address payable addr = addressArray[i];
    (bool sent, bytes memory data) = addr.call{value: 1 ether}("");
    require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```

Enjoy!